# DB2 (and Derby) Pivot Join with Case Statement

Tags: sql, db2, derby

I've seen this [SO question (How can I Pivot a table in DB2?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579143/how-can-i-pivot-a-table-in-db2) and some of the answers/comments mention being able to acheive the same effect with a case statement but I'm struggling mightily to acheive this, probably due to a few years away from much SQL.

Here is a snapshot of some data I have:

```
ID    Date          ErrID   ErrDesc
---------------------------------------
164   2012-09-21    1402    Large V
164   2012-09-21    1409    Missing
416   2012-09-21    1409    Missing
1380  2012-09-21    1411    n - Mis
1500  2012-09-17    1411    n - Mis
1500  2012-09-21    1402    Large V
```

ID *and* Date taken together need to be unique in a query that would return something such as the following, where the empty slots are null.  How can I achieve this, with a case statement or otherwise?  Bear in mind I don't think our version of DB2 supports "decode", and the SQL I need also needs to be able to run on Derby for testing.  Thanks in advance.

```
ID      Date        Err1402     Err1409     Err1411
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
164     2012-09-21  Large V     Missing
416     2012-09-21              Missing
1380    2012-09-21                          n - Mis
1500    2012-09-17                          n - Mis
1500    2012-09-21  Large V
```

Comment: You will use here a sub query ... can you show me the query you build for the 1st diagram

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a version of the query using `CASE` with an aggregate function:

```
select id,
  date,
  max(case when errid = 1402 then ErrDesc else '' end) Err1402,
  max(case when errid = 1409 then ErrDesc else '' end) Err1409,
  max(case when errid = 1411 then ErrDesc else '' end) Err1411
from yourtable
group by id, date
order by id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/caee0/3) (sql server version).  You can replace the empty string with a `null`.

```
select id,
  date,
  max(case when errid = 1402 then ErrDesc else null end) Err1402,
  max(case when errid = 1409 then ErrDesc else null end) Err1409,
  max(case when errid = 1411 then ErrDesc else null end) Err1411
from yourtable
group by id, date
order by id
```

Edit #1: The key to getting this to work properly is the aggregate function.  The `CASE` statement is putting each of the `ErrId` values into the columns but if you do not use the aggregate function you will wind up with multiple rows for each id, date.  So if you use:

```
select id,
  date,
  (case when errid = 1402 then ErrDesc else '' end) Err1402,
  (case when errid = 1409 then ErrDesc else '' end) Err1409,
  (case when errid = 1411 then ErrDesc else '' end) Err1411
from yourtable
order by id
```

The result is:

```
|   ID |                             DATE | ERR1402 | ERR1409 | ERR1411 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  164 | September, 21 2012 00:00:00+0000 | Large V |         |         |
|  164 | September, 21 2012 00:00:00+0000 |         | Missing |         |
|  416 | September, 21 2012 00:00:00+0000 |         | Missing |         |
| 1380 | September, 21 2012 00:00:00+0000 |         |         | n - Mis |
| 1500 | September, 17 2012 00:00:00+0000 |         |         | n - Mis |
| 1500 | September, 21 2012 00:00:00+0000 | Large V |         |         |
```

As you can see the `id=1500` you will get multiple rows which you do not want. So if you tell it that you want the `max()` value for each `errid`, then you will get one row per record.

Comment: Works like a charm though I don't understand precisely how -- any insight into the implementation would be appreciated

Comment: @GeorgeJempty see my edit, I included a brief explanation of how this works. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Got it; I know about aggregate functions of course but "max" just didn't seem germane to me.  Nice bit of trickeration ;)

Comment: @GeorgeJempty since the value is a string you are stuck using `max` or  `min`. :)