# Combining multiple columns into one long column

Tags: php, sql, database, db2

I've looked on the boards and googled a bunch, but I cant find a scenario that fits mine. I have 4 columns

```
+--------+------+------+
| empnum | appn | rate |
+--------+------+------+
|   13   | 1111 |12.34 |
+--------+------+------+
|   13   | 2222 |14.44 |
+--------+------+------+
|   13   | 3333 |15.62 |
+--------+------+------+
|   13   | 4444 |16.12 |
+--------+------+------+
```

each column has the same employee number but different information. I'm trying to combine these 4 columns into 1. The only thing I could find was concatenation. But that won't work for me because these need to go into an array so I can build it in datatables. I would like it to look like this.

```
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|empnum|appn1|rate1|appn2|rate2|appn3|rate3|appn4|rate4|
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  13  |1111 |12.34|2222 |14.44|3333 |15.62|4444 |16.12|
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

As of a week ago all of this information was coming from a flat file. A coworker created a relational table and that's when my brain exploded. We are working on Db2 and I tried to do this in php using a foreach to loop through the array and look for the empnum but I would get the same appn1 for every person. I'd like to do it sql I just can't think of how.

Comment: u need to convert row data into column data check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834290/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-rows-to-columns

Comment: Your google problems might be that you are using the term "column" when you mean "row"

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to Pivot your data.  DB2 doesn't have a PIVOT function, but you can use DECODE to achieve this.  Here's some examples in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579143/how-can-i-pivot-a-table-in-db2).

The result set would look something like:

```
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|empnum|appn1111|appn2222|appn3333|appn4444|
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  13  |12.34   |14.44   |15.62   |16.12   |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: read about the pivot. but if i did the above I could get appn into an array element

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with LISTAGG to get a comma separated list.

Like this:

```
SELECT empnum, LISTAGG(TO_CHAR(appn) || ' - ' || TO_CHAR(rate), ', ') as a_list_4_u
FROM mytable
```

The result should look like this

```
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| empnum |                                                      2 |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|   13   | 1111 - 12.34, 2222 - 14.44, 3333 - 15.62, 4444 - 16.12 |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```