# SQL Transposing columns to rows - PIVOT

Tags: sql, ssis, db2

How can I transpose a table similar to how we can do it in Excel but in SQL or SSIS.

[image: PIVOT/TRASNPOR TABLE SQL]

Comment: Here is an option to do it natively in SSIS: https://www.sqlshack.com/an-overview-of-ssis-pivot-and-ssis-unpivot-transformation/  You could also stage the data and do it in SQL with a similar operation

Comment: You can do this with simple SQL query or do you specifically want to use SSIS?

Comment: As you've tagged DB2 - two examples of Pivot on DB2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579143/how-can-i-pivot-a-table-in-db2 & https://stackoverflow.com/q/15529107/181965

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pivoting in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529107/pivoting-in-db2)